# How to insert a custom post field in a Wordpress Pod?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I recently started using the Wordpress Pods plugin and I'm trying to insert a custom post field in the Pod.
It is not working. Is there any way to do this?

I have created a pod named "network-section"

This pods works:

```
[pods name="network-section" where="id = '4'"]

[/pods]
```

However, I want to use the {@network} field because I have a lot of posts with different network categories.
This is not working:

```
[pods name="network-section" where="id = {@network}"]

[/pods]
```

{@network}"] is a custom post field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your shortcode won't work like that I'm afraid. The ID field is looking for an integer that corresponds to the unique ID of a certain post. That's why your first example works but second one doesn't.

If you want to have a sub-selection of network-section posts, you should find a different way to select them instead of using 'ID" ,(which, by definition, will pull at max only one post).

For instance, you could add a custom taxonomy and use that to filter by in the shortcode, or sooner other field.

The easiest solution might be too create a field in your Post called "network category" then door each of your posts you can give them a particular number.

That way, in your shortcode, you can do:

[pods name="network-section" where="network-category.meta_value = '2'"][/pods]

N.B. you will probably need to use that ".meta_value" to get the right bake in your shortcode, but it depends on how you sweet it up. AND you'll need also need to add your html and other code somewhere (can be in a Pods template or even between shortcode open and close tags) otherwise there will be nothing to display...

Good luck!